# how to call from php stored procedure to load data nested

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

have the next code to load categories and item per categories to build a table:

> $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '123456', 'hdc1');
>
> $categorias = $db->query("call getCategoria(1);");
>
> ```
> if ($categorias) { while ($categoria = $categorias->fetch_object()) {
>
>     $idcategoria = $categoria->id;
>
>     // 2nd Query        
>     if ($items = $db->query("call getItems($idcategoria);")) {
>         // Cycle through results
>         echo "<br />query2";
>
>         while ($item = $items->fetch_object()) {
>             echo $item->descripcion;
>         }
>
>         // Free result set
>         $items->close();
>         $db->next_result();
>     }
>
> }
> // Free result set
> $categorias->close();
> //$db->next_result(); } else echo($db->error);
> ```
>
> // Close connection 
>   $db->close();

the first query is execute succesfully and load the categories but when i want to execute the second query per each category always the resultset is null.

why?? there is not error page, not stored procedure error... why the resultset of items is null ...

Comment: if you made en echo to $idcategoria ?

Comment: yes... and the value of the variable is right

Comment: Did you know a legal categoria value....you could put that number hardcoded on you call...example: call getItems(7)

Comment: yes i did but always the return null but if execute the procedure in the database, brings many rows... 

i never used php and i'm programming like it was anohter languaje i.e. C#

Answer (score 0):

Result sets returned from a stored procedure cannot be fetched correctly using mysqli_query(). The mysqli_query() function combines statement execution and fetching the first result set into a buffered result set, if any. However, there are additional stored procedure result sets hidden from the user which cause mysqli_query() to fail returning the user expected result sets.

Result sets returned from a stored procedure are fetched using mysqli_real_query() or mysqli_multi_query(). Both functions allow fetching any number of result sets returned by a statement, such as CALL